# Postgres - how to stop update of a row once a column in row is not null

Tags: postgresql

I need to setup a constraint that will keep a row from being updated once a specific column in that row is updated with non null data.

Answer (score 2):

You would put a trigger, which returns NULL if the column is already populated, or the NEW object if it is not.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.safeguard_tg_fn() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$BEGIN

    --If the column was not set, allow updating the entire row
    IF OLD.myimportantcol ISNULL THEN
        RETURN NEW; 
    ELSE
    --Else, the column is already populated, cancel the entire update (for this row only)
        RETURN NULL; 
    END IF;
END;$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER safeguard_tg BEFORE UPDATE
   ON public.mytable FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.safeguard_tg_fn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the WHERE clause in your UPDATE

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE column1 is not NULL;
```